# Filter menu_tree_all_data() tree by language?

Tags: 7, routes, i18n-l10n

My site uses multiple languages and I'm using [menu_tree_all_data()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_tree/7) to get the menu tree programmatically. Currently all nodes and their translated nodes use the same menu tree.

If I use a menu block the menu that is displayed is filted by language version of the site the user is on. Which is good.

When calling the menu_tree_all_data() in code to build a menu programmatically it returns the entire tree and there does not seem to be an option to filter the menu by a language.

Does anyone know how to get the menu tree in code filted for a specific language?

Answer (score 6):

I suppose you have i18n_menu.module installed. In this case, use `i18n_menu_localize_tree($MENU_TREE)` to get the tree for the current language.

To get secondary menu, for instance (on template.php):

```
$tree = menu_tree_all_data('menu-secondary');
$variables['secondary_menu_expanded'] = menu_tree_output(i18n_menu_localize_tree($tree));
```

Comment: Useful answer. Actually i had to use:  menu_tree_output(i18n_menu_localize_tree(menu_tree_all_data('mymenu_machine_name')))